# SurrealDB - store binary files

Tags: surrealdb

Is it possible to store binary files (e.g. images) using SurrealDB?
I can't find anything about this in docs.

If not, where can I store images since all the other data is stored in SurrealDB.

Answer (score 2):

SurrealDB wasn't created as a file store. For this purpose, you can use for example object storage. Nearly every cloud service provide object storage.
If you want an open-source solution that can host on your own, you can check MinIO object storage - [github repo](https://github.com/minio/minio).